# After filtering volumes by a tag key, is it possible to obtain the tag value in boto?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

I am trying to create a automatic snapshot program where given the tag key you have on a certain volume, it will view the tag value and act accordingly. 
For example, tag key is 'MakeSnapshot' and tag value is 'Hour-6' where I would make a snapshot every hour and keep 6 total.

```
import boto.ec2
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-east-1',aws_access_key_id='xx', aws_secret_access_key='xx')
vols = conn.get_all_volumes(filters={ 'tag-key' : 'MakeSnapshot' })
for vol in vols:
    initial = #where I pull the tag value from the volume's tag key.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get_all_volumes` method returns a list of `Volume` objects.  Each `Volume` object has an attribute called `tags` that is a Python dictionary containing all of the tags defined for that volume.  For example:

```
import boto.ec2
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-east-1')
volumes = conn.get_all_volumes(filters={'tag-key': 'MakeSnapshot'})
for volume in volumes:
    print(volume.tags)
```

would print something like:

```
{'MakeSnapshot': 'Hour-6'}
```